# Modifying readonly field value from Immediate window

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to learn `readonly` keyword behavior in c#. A `readonly` field can be assigned only in the constructor. But it is possible to assign data to `readonly` field from immediate window at run time. Is it a bug or behavior?

code snippets:

```
public class Foo
{
    public readonly string readOnlyField;

    public Foo(string parameter)
    {
        readOnlyField = parameter;
    }

    public string returnReadOnlyValue()
    {
        return readOnlyField;
    }
}



class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Foo foo = new Foo("Read Only - Init");
            Console.WriteLine(foo.returnReadOnlyValue());

            //Now Modify data from Immediate window
            Console.WriteLine(foo.returnReadOnlyValue());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

[image]

Comment: it's behaviour. Readonly is enforced only at compile time

Comment: @MitchWheat is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's behaviour.

`Readonly` is enforced only at compile time

Answer (score 4):

I confirm that readonly members could be assigned in the debugger before, but apparently things have changed at some point.

Today in the `Immediate Window` of VS2015, I get:

```
error CS0191: A readonly field cannot be assigned to (except in a constructor or a variable initializer)
```

Answer (score 2):

As @MitchWheat stated, `readonly` is only enforced at compile time. If you need a variable to never be changed even when debugging, use a `const` instead.

More info at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acdd6hb7.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

`readonly` does one thing only: indicate the programmers' intent that the field in question never be changed.

Therefore any attempt in the program to change it shows a problem with the programmers' work: Either they were incorrect when they marked the field `readonly` or they were incorrect when they attempted to change it. The compiler helpfully refuses to compile the program until this is resolved one way or another.

The compiler *could* theoretically put this field into some sort of read-only or protected memory if such were available and efficient. It's most likely not going to though, with it being a lot more straight forward to just store it somewhere on the same stack or heap as non-`readonly` fields.

And since that means it's represented by some 1s and 0s somewhere in memory, there is nothing to prevent something else from changing those 1s and 0s, including through a debugger. You can likewise change the value through refection from within the .NET code.

And ultimately, why not? It's done its job.

Consider a three-pin electrical socket with a separate earth, live and neutral. If I try to plug this in such as the earth pin goes in the live hole, this won't fit, and so I am prevented from accidentally doing something very stupid.

If I take the plug apart and re-wire it so that the earth wire is connected to the live pin, I can then plug it into the socket and make the metal casing live.

This isn't a bug in the design of the plugs and sockets. Either I had a good reason for doing this (at a technical level anyway, the only actual reason I can think for is attempting homicide) or I was going out of my way to be stupid.

Likewise, if you change a `readonly` field, either you have a good reason for it, or you are going out of your way to be stupid. You can only protect people from themselves so much.

(Of course, you might want to do something stupid on a machine out of malice, but that is for the access controls that prevent reflection without sufficient trust or debugging processes run by other accounts without administrator access, to prevent).